# Is Linq to NHibernate no longer active?

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I haven't seen an update since 2009. I'd like to use it but not if it will prevent me from upgrading NHibernate versions in the future.

Answer (score 6):

As of NHibernate 3.0, LINQ support is built into the framework. No need for any separate contrib library. The contrib library provided LINQ support for NHibernate 2.x, that's why you don't see any recent updates.